# Docker log files not persisting

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to persist the log files I am writing with Winston (NodeJs), but the files are empty once I rebuild the container, these are the commands:

```
docker run --name mongo_db -v mongo-data:/data/db -d mongo
docker build -t andy/docker-test .
docker run -d -p 49160:8080 --name docker_test -v app-data:/data --link=mongo_db:mongodb andy/docker-test
```

In the root of my project folder I have created a directory called 'data' where the log file is supposedly being saved.

I can read the file, however when I rebuild my container the file is empty again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Image can be rebuilt, container can be restarted. What do you mean by "rebuild a container"?

Comment: you need to provide some more information.  "root of my project folder" isn't clear - and it's not clear how you're creating the app-data volume you're "mounting" the container's /data directory to (volumes normally get created in /var/lib/docker/volumes)

Comment: are you sure your app is appending to the file and not overwriting it?

Comment: @Yuankun I run the commands I included above, the correct term would be 'rebuild the image' instead. Thanks

Comment: @jameygraham with 'root of my project folder' I actually refer to a directory I have created for my containerised NodeJs source code in my host machine (Mac OX) which is located in '~/Work/test'. in my Dockerfile I have added `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` and `VOLUME ["/data"]`. I am not specifically creating or referencing the app-data volume anywhere else.

Comment: @raghulmz I am using a Winston transport like this `new transports.File({ filename: './data/logs/app.log', timestamp: true }),` As far as I know Winston appends by default.

Comment: Should you be using /data/logs/app.log instead ? So that the mapped volume is used.

Comment: last q - when you say "i can read the file" - read from where?  can you see a file being created on the host filesystem (in the app-data volume?) or read the file from the container itself?  I'm noticing that the volume is defined as /data [from directory root], but the file you create is ./data [relative to process working dir..which _may_ be the filesystem root].  but  basically i'm trying to determine if you are actually seeing the log file on the host filesystem